# Should I test the trend by the test of Mann-kendall or by the slope

Tags: statistical-significance, trend

Here is a graph of the 29 patients in my study, with three follow-up periods.
Not all patients completed all three follow-ups
I want to test the overall trend to see if it is significantly different from 0 and if it is increasing or decreasing. I'm wondering if the best test to do is the Mann-kendall test or if it's the slope that I should test.
[image]